# While syntax in matlab

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I am aware of the general syntax for the while loop in matlab, which general includes

While statement
Do expression things
End

But what does

```
while (1) 
...
```

mean?

Why is there a (1), and no relational Or logic operator?

Comment: 1 is always true. The while loop never ends. It’s an infinite loop.

Comment: You need a [break statement](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html) to terminate the execution of the `while (1)` loop

Answer (score 1):

Every time you use structures like "while" or "if" they have a condition inside the parenthesis.
If that condition is true, the code inside is executed. Something being true translates to the Boolean 1.
Try this command in Matlab:

```
3>2
```

Matlab will tell you that this statement is a true with the Boolean answer '1'.
If you put `while(1)`, it is the same as putting `while(3>2)`, both statements are always true, so the code inside is going to be executed an infinite amount of times (if there aren't any command inside that loop that might break it).